# DAX | Sum up rows for a column based on conditions in another column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to DAX, I have a data which looks like -

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 20 |
| A | 10 |
| B | 30 |
| B | 20 |

My output should be -

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | 30 |
| A | 10 | 30 |
| B | 30 | 50 |
| B | 20 | 50 |

I have tried writing a measure but it dosnt work -

```
col3 =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Sheet1[col2] ),
    FILTER (
        ALLSELECTED ( Sheet1 ),
        Sheet1[col1] == Sheet1[col1]
    )
)
```

Comment: The DAX formula doesn't look reasonable. How is col3 calculated?

Comment: sorry @Peter its my bad, eited now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are actually looking for a formula to calculate **col3**, take this one here and put all cols into a table visual.

```
col3 = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Sheet1'[col2]),
    ALLEXCEPT(
        'Sheet1',
        'Sheet1'[col1]
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: You might wonder that this formula doesn't have an "explicit condition", but this condition is established by the "filter context" in the table visual.